# React-Admin can't post to ASP.Net Core API

Tags: asp.net, reactjs, asp.net-core-webapi, react-admin, asp.net-core-3.1

I am trying to connect ASP.NET Core 3 api with React-Admin. So far I can list the entries from the DB and show a single record - apparently the two GET methods are working fine. (Sticking to this [example](https://github.com/tYoshiyuki/dotnet-core-react-admin))

When I try to Create a record though with a POST method I receive a 400 Bad Request and can't track the issue.

My App.js looks like this:

```
import simpleRestProvider from 'ra-data-simple-rest';
import realApi from './dataProvider/myDataProvider';

const dataProvider = simpleRestProvider('api/');

const App = () =>
    <Admin        
        dashboard={Dashboard}
        dataProvider={realApi}        
    >
        <Resource name={projects.basePath} {...projects.crud} />
        ...
    </Admin>;
```

I have custom dataProvider which is copied from the official react-admin tutorial

```
    export default (type, resource, params) => {    
    let url = '';
    const options = { 
        headers: new Headers({
            Accept: 'application/json',
            "Content-Type": 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        }),
    };

    let query = "";
    switch (type) {
        case GET_LIST: {
            const { page, perPage } = params.pagination;
            const { field, order } = params.sort;
            query = {
                sort: JSON.stringify([field, order]),
                range: JSON.stringify([
                    (page - 1) * perPage,
                    page * perPage - 1,
                ]),
                filter: JSON.stringify(params.filter),
            };
            url = `${apiUrl}/${resource}?${stringify(query)}`;
            break;
        }
        case GET_ONE:
            url = `${apiUrl}/${resource}/${params.id}`;
            break;
        case CREATE:
            url = `${apiUrl}/${resource}`;
            options.method = 'POST';
            options.body = JSON.stringify(params.data);
            break;
        case UPDATE:
            url = `${apiUrl}/${resource}/${params.id}`;
            options.method = 'PUT';
            options.body = JSON.stringify(params.data);
            break;
        case UPDATE_MANY:
            query = {
                filter: JSON.stringify({ id: params.ids }),
            };
            url = `${apiUrl}/${resource}?${stringify(query)}`;
            options.method = 'PATCH';
            options.body = JSON.stringify(params.data);
            break;
        case DELETE:
            url = `${apiUrl}/${resource}/${params.id}`;
            options.method = 'DELETE';
            break;
        case DELETE_MANY:
            query = {
                filter: JSON.stringify({ id: params.ids }),
            };
            url = `${apiUrl}/${resource}?${stringify(query)}`;
            options.method = 'DELETE';
            break;
        case GET_MANY: {
            query = {
                filter: JSON.stringify({ id: params.ids }),
            };
            url = `${apiUrl}/${resource}?${stringify(query)}`;
            break;
        }
        case GET_MANY_REFERENCE: {
            const { page, perPage } = params.pagination;
            const { field, order } = params.sort;
            query = {
                sort: JSON.stringify([field, order]),
                range: JSON.stringify([
                    (page - 1) * perPage,
                    page * perPage - 1,
                ]),
                filter: JSON.stringify({
                    ...params.filter,
                    [params.target]: params.id,
                }),
            };
            url = `${apiUrl}/${resource}?${stringify(query)}`;
            break;
        }
        default:
            throw new Error(`Unsupported Data Provider request type ${type}`);
    }


    let headers;
    return fetch(url, options)
        .then(res => {
            headers = res.headers;
            debugger
            return res.json();
        })
        .then(json => {
            switch (type) {
                case GET_LIST:
                case GET_MANY_REFERENCE:
                    if (!headers.has('content-range')) {
                        throw new Error(
                            'The Content-Range header is missing in the HTTP Response. The simple REST data provider expects responses for lists of resources to contain this header with the total number of results to build the pagination. If you are using CORS, did you declare Content-Range in the Access-Control-Expose-Headers header?'
                        );
                    }
                    return {
                        data: json,
                        total: parseInt(
                            headers
                                .get('content-range')
                                .split('/')
                                .pop(),
                            10
                        ),
                    };
                case CREATE:
                    return { data: { ...params.data, id: json.id } };
                default:
                    return { data: json };
            }
        });
};
```

And finally there is the ASP.NET Controller:

```
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public abstract class RaController<T> : ControllerBase, IRaController<T> where T : class, new()
    {

        protected readonly IDveDbContext _context;
        protected DbSet<T> _table;

        public RaController(IDveDbContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
            _table = _context.Set<T>();
        }

        [HttpGet("{id}")]
        public async Task<ActionResult<T>> Get(int id)
        {
            var entity = await _table.FindAsync(id);

            if (entity == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            return entity;
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<ActionResult<T>> Post(T entity)
        {
            _table.Add(entity);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            var id = (int)typeof(T).GetProperty("Id").GetValue(entity);
            return Ok(await _table.FindAsync(id));
        }
    }
```

And the exact ProjectsController

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class ProjectsController : RaController<Project>
{
    private IProjectService projectService;

    public ProjectsController(IProjectService projectService, IDveDbContext dbContext)
        : base (dbContext)
    {
        this.projectService = projectService;
    }
}
```

I've been searching around for a solution but couldn't find any. If somebody give a hint on where the problem might be or provide an example for successflly integrated ASP.Net Core with React-Admin I would be extremely thankful!

Answer (score 4):

I've gotten it to work well with a .net REST API, starting with the same pieces you started with.  I see a few issues in yours:

#### 1. Use a better data provider.

The built-in provider is more of an example.  It only works with an identifier of "id."  [zachrybaker/ra-data-rest-client](https://github.com/zachrybaker/ra-data-rest-client) allows for you to have more realistic flexibility in what your identifier is called, for existing APIs.

#### 2. Pattern your base controller.

Your base controller needs some adjustment.  It should describe what it produces (application/json) and the POST method is "Create" not "Post" since you need to differentiate between create(insert) and update (hence the 404).

I'll also note that your base method could use to describe what type if identifier, rather than assuming int, if you need that.  Here's mine.  I'm hoping to open source the whole thing, stay tuned.

```
[ApiController]
[Produces("application/json")]
public abstract class EntityWithIdControllerBase<TEntity,  TReadModel, TCreateModel, TUpdateModel, TIndentifier> : BaseEFCoreAPIController
    where TEntity : class, IHaveIdentifier<TIndentifier>
{

////....
////constructor....
////....

    [HttpPost("")]

    public async virtual Task<ActionResult<TReadModel>> Create(CancellationToken cancellationToken, TCreateModel createModel)
    {
        return await CreateModel(createModel, cancellationToken);
    }
////....
    protected virtual async Task<TReadModel> CreateModel(TCreateModel createModel, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken))
    {
        // create new entity from model
        var entity = Mapper.Map<TEntity>(createModel);

        // add to data set, id should be generated
        await DataContext
            .Set<TEntity>()
            .AddAsync(entity, cancellationToken);

        // save to database
        await DataContext
            .SaveChangesAsync(cancellationToken);

        // convert to read model
        var readModel = await ReadModel(entity.Id, cancellationToken);

        return readModel;
    }      
////....
    protected virtual async Task<TReadModel> ReadModel(TIndentifier id, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken))
    {
        var model = await IncludeTheseForDetailResponse(DataContext
            .Set<TEntity>()
            .AsNoTracking())
            .Where(GetIdentifierEqualityFn(id))
            .ProjectTo<TReadModel>(Mapper.ConfigurationProvider)
            .FirstOrDefaultAsync(cancellationToken);

        return model;
    }
////....
    #region Expressions
    protected virtual Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> IdentityExpressionFn(ExpressionStarter<TEntity> expressionStarter, JToken token)  
    {
        return expressionStarter.Or(GetIdentifierEqualityFn(token.Value<TIndentifier>()));
    }
    
    protected abstract Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> GetIdentifierEqualityFn(TIndentifier o);
    
    /// <summary>
    /// When you need to include related entities on the detail response, you can add them via this IQueryable by overriding this function 
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="queryable"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    protected virtual IQueryable<TEntity> IncludeTheseForDetailResponse(IQueryable<TEntity> queryable) => queryable;
    #endregion Expressions
}
```

Just to let you know, the real fun begins when you start to deal with the filtering ability of react admin.  That is where my "Expressions" come into play.  I have a base class that can leverage expression builders and uses LinqKit for dynamic when really necessary.

Many of my controllers are Guid, so I have an intermediate controller for that:

```
[ApiController]
[Produces("application/json")]
public abstract class EntityWithGuidIdController<TEntity,  TReadModel, TCreateModel, TUpdateModel> : 
    EntityWithIdControllerBase<TEntity,  TReadModel, TCreateModel, TUpdateModel, Guid>
    where TEntity : class, IHaveIdentifier<Guid>, new()
    
{
////....
////constructor....
////....
    #region Expressions
    /// <summary>
    /// If you need to use a primay key other than "Id", then override this.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="g"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    protected override Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> GetIdentifierEqualityFn(Guid g)  => (x => x.Id == g);

    protected override Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> IdentityExpressionFn(ExpressionStarter<TEntity> expressionStarter, JToken token)  
    {
        if (Guid.TryParse((string)token, out Guid g))
            return expressionStarter.Or(GetIdentifierEqualityFn(g));
    
        Debug.WriteLine((string)token + " Is NOT a valid Guid.  why was it sent?");
        return null;
    }
    #endregion Expressions
}
```

Then I can consume it as simply as this -> in this case the detail response also includes a second object:

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class UserController : EntityWithGuidIdController<User, UserReadModel, UserCreateModel, UserUpdateModel>
{
    public UserController(ZachTestContext dataContext, IMapper mapper) : base(dataContext, mapper, CacheValidInterval.OneDay)
    { }

    // Include the Adloc on the detail response.
    protected override IQueryable<User> IncludeTheseForDetailResponse(IQueryable<User> queryable) => queryable.Include(x => x.Adloc);
}
```